# Ruby .each not cycling through array like expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, tags, each

Extreme Ruby/Rails novice here: I'm trying to link_to a search action for each individual post contained in a block:

```
<% split_tags = post.tags.split(',') %> # returns ["food", "computers", "health"] %>
<p>Keywords: <%= split_tags.each {|tag| link_to(tag, front_search_tag_path(:tag => tag))}) %></p>
```

but all it returns is `Keywords: ["food", "computers", "health"]`. 
Shouldn't .each iterate over the array and provide a link to each search_tag_path with the tag as a parameter?

Comment: Maybe try #map instead of #each?

Comment: <%= ... %> returns the last expression evaluated. `.each` returns the original Array, so you want <% .each do |tag| %><%= link_to ... %><% end %>

Comment: Shoot, can't believe I made that novice mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, #each just performs a block, it does not accumulate any data.

```
[1, 2, 3].each{ |n| "Link to item #{n}" } #=> [1, 2, 3]
```

You have two options, use map to accumulate data:

```
[1, 2, 3].map{ |n| "Link to item #{n}" }.join("\n") #=> "Link to item 1\nLink to item 2\nLink to item 3"
```

Or output directly in the block:

```
[1, 2, 3].each{ |n| puts "Link to item #{n}" }
```

Prints:

```
Link to item 1
Link to item 2
Link to item 3
```

In your case this would be the following two options. I prefer the latter.

```
<p>Keywords: <%=raw split_tags.map{|tag| link_to(tag)}.join %></p>

<p> Keywords:
  <% split_tags.each do |tag| %>
    <%= link_to(tag) %>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant

```
<% split_tags = post.tags.split(',') %> # returns ["food", "computers", "health"] %>
<p>Keywords:
  <% split_tags.each do |tag| %>
  <%= link_to(tag, front_search_tag_path(:tag => tag)) %>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

or

```
<% split_tags = post.tags.split(',') %> # returns ["food", "computers", "health"] %>
<p>Keywords:
  <%= split_tags.map{|tag| link_to(tag, front_search_tag_path(:tag => tag))}.join %>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the return value for `Array#each` is the array itself (see http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-each)

You will want to use `Array#collect` (or its alias, `map`) which will return an array of the links (see http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map).  You can then turn that array into a single string with join.  So, your code would look like

```
<% split_tags = post.tags.split(',') %>
<p>Keywords: <%= split_tags.collect {|tag| link_to(tag, front_search_tag_path(:tag => tag))}).join %></p>
```

However that might require the `.html_safe` after the `.join`. Better yet, do something like:

```
<% split_tags = post.tags.split(',') %>
<p>Keywords: 
<% split_tags.each do |tag| %>
  <%= link_to(tag, front_search_tag_path(:tag => tag)) %>
<% end %>
</p>
```